# Not displaying posts that are in the past. ACF date > date

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Trying to make posts that are in the past compared to ACF `the_field('end_date')`

Current code:

```php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name' => 'gold',
    'meta_key'    => 'status',
    'meta_value'  => 'active',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => date("y-m-d"),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => "DATE"
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the `meta_query` proprety and looking at your code you seem to have two meta values mixed, so we need to combine them.

```php
$loop = new WP_Query([
    'category_name'  => 'gold',
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'and',
        [
            'key'   => 'status',
            'value' => 'active'
        ],
        [
            'key'     => 'end_date',
            'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Also `date('y-m-d')` return the current date (if we go by the date this answer was creates it will return 21-10-14), that is not a valid date format you this compare will not work.
Even if it was are looking for posts that are equal or older then the current date, which, I assume is not correct (I cound be wrong so feel free to correct me on that =]).

You need to make sure that you have stored a valide date format in that meta field, needs to be `date('Y-m-d')` instead of `date('y-m-d')`, notice the upper case Y.

Comment: Woop! Yes!

That did the trick! I dont have enough reputation, any viewers please upvote.